Limit Comparison Test for Double Improper Integral Proof
I am studying from the book Sudhir R. Ghorpade, Balmohan V. Limaye -
A Course in Multivariable Calculus and Analysis at the moment and I am specifically interested in the convergence of double improper integrals. The Limit Comparison test for double improper integrals exist, but the book does not prove or derive it unfortunately, which I was looking for. It is said on page 432 that
''One can derive Limit Comparison Test and Root Test for improper double integrals from Proposition 7.61. These tests involve the concept of uniform convergence, which we have not introduced in this book. Hence we refrain
from discussing them here''
I am asking for help if anyone has advice for the proof or deriving the Limit Comparison Test for double improper integrals, or any other source I could find it in.
This is the proposition 7.6.1 mentioned
Let $f : [a, \infty) \times [c, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f$ is integrable on $[a, x] \times [c, y]$ for each fixed $(x, y) \geq (a, c)$, the Riemann integral $\int_a^x  |f(s, t)| \, ds \, dt$ exists for each fixed $(x, t) \geq (a, c)$, and the Riemann integral $\int_c^y |f(s, t)| \, dt \, ds$ exists for each fixed $(s, y) \geq (a, c)$. Then the improper double integral $\iint_{[a,\infty) \times [c,\infty)} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if the following conditions hold:
i. There are $(s_0, t_0) \geq (a, c)$ and $a_0 > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\iint_{[s_0,x] \times [t_0,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) \leq a_0 \quad \text{for all } (x, y) \geq (s_0, t_0).
\end{equation}
ii. For each fixed $x > a$, the improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_c^\infty \left( \int_a^x |f(s, t)| \, ds \right) dt
\end{equation}
is convergent, and for each fixed $y > c$, the improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_a^\infty \left( \int_c^y |f(s, t)| \, dt \right) ds
\end{equation}
is convergent.
Proof
Since the function $|f|$ is integrable on $[a, x] \times [c, y]$, we may define
\begin{equation}
F(x,y) := \iint_{[a,x] \times [c,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) \quad \text{for } (x, y) \geq (a, c).
\end{equation}
By Fubini's Theorem on Rectangles (Proposition 5.28),
\begin{equation}
F(x, y) = \int_a^x \left( \int_c^y |f(s, t)| \, dt \right) ds = \int_c^y \left( \int_a^x |f(s, t)| \, ds \right) dt \quad \text{for } (x, y) \geq (a, c).
\end{equation}
Suppose $\iint_{[a,\infty) \times [c,\infty)} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t)$ is absolutely convergent. Since $|f(s, t)| \geq 0$ for all $(s, t) \geq (a, c)$, Proposition 7.55 shows that the function $F$ is bounded above. Hence condition (i) holds with $(s_0, t_0) := (a, c)$ and $a_0 := \sup \{ F(x, y) : (x, y) \geq (a, c) \}$. Also, in view of the first equality displayed above, for each fixed $x > a$, we have
\begin{equation}
\sup \left\{ \int_c^y \left( \int_a^x |f(s, t)| \, ds \right) dt : y > c \right\} \leq a_0,
\end{equation}
so that the improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_c^\infty \left( \int_a^x |f(s, t)| \, ds \right) dt
\end{equation}
is convergent. Similarly, for each fixed $y > c$, the improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_a^\infty \left( \int_c^y |f(s, t)| \, dt \right) ds
\end{equation}
is convergent.
Conversely, assume that conditions (i) and (ii) hold. Let $(s_0, t_0) \geq (a, c)$ and $a_0 > 0$ be such that
\begin{equation}
\iint_{[s_0,x] \times [t_0,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) \leq a_0 \quad \text{for all } (x, y) \geq (s_0, t_0).
\end{equation}
By Domain Additivity (Proposition 5.9),
\begin{equation}
F(x, y) = \iint_{[a,x] \times [c,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) = \iint_{[s_0,x] \times [t_0,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) + \iint_{[a,s_0] \times [c,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) + \iint_{[s_0,x] \times [c,t_0]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) \quad \text{for all } (x, y) \geq (s_0, t_0).
\end{equation}
Now since the improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_a^{s_0} \left( \int_c^y |f(s, t)| \, ds \right) dt
\end{equation}
is convergent, there is $B_0 > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\iint_{[a,s_0] \times [c,y]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) \leq B_0 \quad \text{for all } y \geq c.
\end{equation}
Similarly, since the improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_c^{t_0} \left( \int_{s_0}^x |f(s, t)| \, dt \right) ds
\end{equation}
is convergent, there is $y_0 > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{[s_0,x] \times [c,t_0]} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t) \leq y_0 \quad \text{for all } x \geq a.
\end{equation}
Hence $F(x, y) \leq a_0 + B_0 + y_0$ for all $(x, y) \geq (s_0, t_0)$. This shows that the monotonically increasing function $F$ is bounded on $[a, \infty) \times [c, \infty)$. Thus, by Proposition 7.55, $\iint_{[a,\infty) \times [c,\infty)} |f(s, t)| \, d(s, t)$ is absolutely convergent.
